# ListView and WebView Scrolling

Tags: android-listview, webview, android

I am developing an app which have a webview component and a list view component. I have a transparent layout on my webview to capture all the user event. I execute a javascript scroll function on the webview whenever the user is trying to scroll. Every-time the function is called, webview get scrolled and it returns a value which is used to scroll my list view. To scroll my list view I am using **myListView.setSelectionFromTop(pos, y)**. The problem here is if I disable scrolling for the listview, the webview scrolls smoothly. But if the listview is enable, the webview doesn't scroll smoothly. My ultimate aim is to scroll listview and webView simultaneously. But it seems while scrolling listview it blocks the UI thread and hence make the scrolling of the webview slow.

Can anyone suggest me how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

@MysticMagic Here is my xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   xmlns:widget="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"> 
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:divider="#D3D0D9"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#E2E2E2"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"             
                android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:fillViewport="true" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webLayout"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relLayout">
                <WebView 
                    android:id="@+id/webView" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="none">
                </WebView> 
                <com.example.view.CustomView
                     android:id="@+id/transparentView"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```